# .Net Core - Building to release does not copy NUGET dependencies

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

I have a console .net core app.
It references a few nuget packages.
Now that it's ready to deploy, when i'm building to release, the nuget references are not coming along so i'm getting a bunch of file not found...

how can i fix this?

Comment: dotnet build --configuration Release

Comment: build brings nuget packages

Comment: @SilentTremor no luck there... NUGET packs related dlls are still missing...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's the difference between building (for testing) and publishing (for deployment to production). `dotnet build` will build your application for local testing and usage. It will assume that nuget dependencies are present on the machine. If you want to build for deployment, use `dotnet publish` instead:

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

Then look into the `./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.0/publish` directory. It should contain all your dependencies too.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli for more details.